# What is the request to "Confirm Mac Password" about?

Tags: macos, icloud, password

Since changing my Mac password I constantly see the message "" in my iCloud settings.

[image]

What is this for:

- What does providing this password do?
- What does *not* providing this password *not* to (e.g., are there features I'll miss out on)?
- Can I safely ignore it?
- Is it something I should worry about (and if so, how do I get rid of it)?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Not a dupe: read the questions.

Comment: Did you try signing out of iCloud completely and then signing in again as the answer to the other question recommends? Please list the things you've tried already to get this reopened.

Comment: @nohillside: Still not reading the question: What is it for? What would the consequences of ignoring this be?

Comment: You have several questions in there in that case. „What is it for“ and „how do I get rid of it“. Please edit your question to ask only one _or_ the other. But please keep in mind that „what is the reason for this“ type of questions often get closed as being primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @nohillside: I'm not sure what's unclear about "what's it for": specifically, the implications: What does providing this password do? What does not providing this password not to? Can I safely ignore it? Is it something I should worry about? All of those questions are answered by "what's it for", and none of them are "opinion based".

Comment: Then please update your question to ask what you want to know. Right now it reads "What is this for, and how do I get rid of it", which is not what you elaborated on in the comments above.